# Applying for UK (and/or Schengen Visa) with 1 passport while I have 2

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, passports

Turkish citizen. I will need to apply and will need passport for the following processes in the coming months:

1. Ireland naturalization process (am legal resident)
2. A Schengen Visa from the country I intend to visit (probably Spain/Portugal)
3. A UK Visa

Now since the 1st process will take sometime, effectively holding my passport hostage, I will get a second Turkish passport (which is doable). I need to provide my original passport to the 1st process but not necessarily the newly issued one.

I intend to apply to the other 2 visa applications with a newly issued one, providing scans of my original passport and probably with a document supporting that I have my passport being held by the authorities.

Would this create any issues?

Comment: Without knowing your nationality. residency and the countries involved this is hard to say...

Comment: Which country retains your passport during the naturalization process? Sounds highly irregular to me.

Comment: Added information for countries.

Comment: Applying for a second passport plus visa application time may be longer than the 'passport hostage' time: [Becoming an Irish citizen through naturalisation](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/becoming_an_irish_citizen_through_naturalisation.html#lbd4aa) *Allow at least 6 weeks for your passport to be returned to you.*

Comment: I wish that were true. Turkish embassy issues a new passport in ~3 working days while I know people whose passport is with the Irish Naturalisation office for ~5 months now.